# Stop AWS Elastic Beanstalk from creating new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is it possible to prevent Amazon Elastic Beanstalk from dropping an instance and creating a new one on its own, like for it to ask for approval first. I run a redis instance locally because elasticache is quite expensive and I dont want to have to keep installing and starting redis every time elastic beanstalk drops the instance and starts a new one. Is it possible to make sure it keeps a specific instance of EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) is meant for scaling web applications, so I'm not sure it's the right tool here.

If you are just looking to run a single instance with a manual install of redis at  low cost, then launching an EC2 instance directly (rather than using Elastic Beanstalk) may be more appropriate?

You would of course then need to bear in mind that the EC2 would not automatically recover in the event of a problem, but it sounds like you don't have that currently anyway.